# Reemplazar "/" por "-" dado en un string javascript y jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

tengo el siguente problema la cual consiste que estoy obteniendo un string de un input que contiene una fecha de la siguente manera "28/04/2018", despues necesito pasarlo a otro input para enviarlo desde un formulario.

Estoy intentado reemplazar de la siguente manera:
Esta la que obtengo atraves de jquery

```
var fecha = "28/04/2018"
```

Lo estoy intentando reemplazar de la siguiente manera

```
var nfecha = fecha.replace("//g", "-");
```

Espero su ayuda, gracias...

Comment: Que error te esta dando ?? asi te deberia de funcionar solo que te falta es var fecha = nfecha;

Comment: No manda error simplemente me lo devuelve tal cual como entra

Answer (score 6):

Según [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9823754/9015852), debes hacerlo de esta forma:

```js
var fecha = "28/04/2018"
var diaMesAño = fecha.replace(/\//g, '-');
console.log(diaMesAño);
```

**Edit**

Para responder a los comentarios. Una opción habría sido ponerlo todo desde el principio de esta forma:

```js
var fecha = "23/11/2018"
var diaMesAño = fecha.split('/');
var formateado = diaMesAño[2] + '-' + diaMesAño[1] + '-' + diaMesAño[0];

console.log(formateado);
```

Comment: Si me funciono tu aporte. Ahora me sale el siguente error para pasarlo al input. **The specified value "23-11-2018" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".**

Comment: Vale, significa que debes enviarlo al input de esta forma: 2018-11-23. Es decir año-mes-día. Ahora pongo algo

Comment: Como puedo transformar a ese formato.?

Comment: Ya está modificado

Comment: Podrías aceptar la respuesta si te ha sido útil :-)

Answer (score 1):

en mi trabajo usamos este código

```
Fecha.split("/").join("-")
```

Lo que hace es con el Split separa el string en un vector, dividido por las / y con join concatena el vector poniendo de separación el -

Espero te ayude, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que pides en los comentarios, esta podría ser tu solución:

```js
var fecha = "28/04/2018"
var splitDate = fecha.split("/");
var nuevaFecha = splitDate[2]+"-"+splitDate[1]+"-"+splitDate[0];
console.log( nuevaFecha);
```