# ¿Cómo hacer un Split() con múltiples separadores Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, split

tengo esta fecha  **2018-05-10T18:30:31** , y tengo que convertir esto para que el resultado final tener esto:

**10/05/2018**

**12:34**

es decir tener por un lado la hora en formato **HH:mm**  y la fecha en formato **dd/MM/yyy**.

Comment: Tienes que escribir lo que has hecho hasta ahora para poder ayudarte. Mira esta guía https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: he modificado la pregunta, ahora solo necesito hacer un esplit con multiples separadores y soucionado.

Comment: Podrías hacer que esta fecha `2018-05-10T18:30:31` coincida con esta `19/05/2018`? Así estaría más claro

Comment: Podrias usar un regex, pero tal vez sea mas sencillo primero hacer un split por `T`, y luego en el primer elemento resultante un split por `-` y en el segundo uno por `:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes explotar la cadena usando una expresión regular:

```
var fecha='2018-05-10T18:30:31',
    arrayfecha=fecha.split(/-|T|:/);
```

Que separa todos los componentes en un array `[año, mes, dia, hora, minuto, segundo]`

```js
var fecha='2018-05-10T18:30:31',
    arrayfecha=fecha.split(/-|T|:/),
    fecha_formateada=arrayfecha.splice(0,3).reverse().join('/'),
    segundos=arrayfecha.pop(),
    hora_formateada= arrayfecha.join(':');
    
console.log(fecha_formateada);
console.log(hora_formateada);
```

Answer (score 2):

Podrías hacer [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/163651/reemplazar-por-dado-en-un-string-javascript-y-jquery/163658#163658). Recuerda que esto se trata de mostrar que has hecho un esfuerzo en resolver el problema y que nosotros te ayudemos donde estás atascado

```js
let firstDate= "2018-05-10T18:30:31";

let firstArray = firstDate.split("T");

let dma = firstArray[0].split('-');
let fmt = dma[2] + '/' + dma[1] + '/' + dma[0];

let hms = firstArray[1].split(":");
let hm = hms[0] + ":" + hms[1];

console.log(fmt);
console.log(hm);
```